# foreach not showing results in view

Tags: codeigniter, view, foreach

my controller is

```
<?php

class Blog extends Controller {

function Blog()
    {
        parent::Controller();

    }


    function index()
{

        $data['title']= "this is a blog";
        $data['heading']="Pretty wise";
        $data['query']= $this->db->get('entries');
        $this->load->view('blogview.php',$data);

}


}
?>
```

my view file is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?= $title ?></title>

</head>
  <body>
    <h1> <?=$heading?></h1>

     <?php foreach($query->result() as $row): ?>

      <h3><?= $row->title ?></h3>
      <p><?= $row->body ?></p>

      <hr>


     <?php endforeach; ?>



   </body>
   </html>
```

the output of this is a page with something like this

```
title ?>
body ?> 
 ---------------------
title ?>
body ?>
 ---------------------
```

pretty missed up huh ? lol

i am sure about other database connectivity stuff, 
i am trying to output two rows in my DB

Comment: The title in firefox is  <?= $title ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have short tags turned on in your apache install.

Short tags allow you to do `<?= ?>` rather than `<?php echo($title); ?>`